# when the cards are correct javascript should display message

Tags: javascript

Code that allows card movement; It is javascript code and when the cards are correct message should display

you can move the cards but the message is not displayed

https://jsfiddle.net/bsrm0z8L

There is another similar code that works. If that is achievable with vanilla javascript that would be better.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Cards</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<style>
body {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #333;
}

/* Give headings their own font */

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

/* Main content area */

#content {
  margin: 80px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Header/footer boxes */

.wideBox {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.wideBox h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* Slots for final card positions */

#cardSlots {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background: #ddf;
}

/* The initial pile of unsorted cards */

#cardPile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffd;
}

#cardSlots, #cardPile {
  width: 910px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* Individual cards and slots */

#cardSlots div, #cardPile div {
  float: left;
  width: 58px;
  height: 78px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

#cardSlots div:first-child, #cardPile div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}

#cardSlots div {
  border-style: dashed;
}

#cardPile div {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}

#cardPile div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* Individually coloured cards */

#card1.correct { background: red; }
#card2.correct { background: brown; }
#card3.correct { background: orange; }
#card4.correct { background: yellow; }
#card5.correct { background: green; }
#card6.correct { background: cyan; }
#card7.correct { background: blue; }
#card8.correct { background: indigo; }
#card9.correct { background: purple; }
#card10.correct { background: violet; }


/* "You did it!" message */
#successMessage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #dfd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() 
{

  var words = ['F', 'R', 'A', 'N','C','E'];
  for ( var i=1; i<=6; i++ ) 
  {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'number', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      containment: '#content',  
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',   
      drop: handleDropEvent      
    } );
  }  
  
  var numbers = ['F', 'R', 'A', 'N','C','E'];
  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<6; i++ ) 
  {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }
  
function handleDropEvent( event, ui )
{
  var draggable = ui.draggable;  
  var android = $(this).data( 'Y' );
  var science = ui.draggable.data( 'N' );  
  if ( android == science ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  }   
  
}
   
  if ( correctCards == 6 ) 
  {
  window.alert("Hello world!");
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }  
} 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="content">  

  <div id="cardPile"> </div>
  <div id="cardSlots"> </div>  
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is expected using a `background-image` with `background-size:cover`. Unless the element with the background image has the exact same aspect ratio as the image, it will not show the entire image.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `background-size: cover;`.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#cover)

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

Don't use `cover` for `background-size`.

Comment: that question has been changed

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your CSS :

```
.ylid.content
```